# Is it possible to fix the port number for graphql altair?

Tags: django, cors, django-csrf, django-cors-headers

I'm using Django as backend providing a GraphQL API. I'm using Django's builtin support for [Cross Site Request Forgery protection (CSRF protection)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/) and django-cors-headers to enable the use of the [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) mechanism. To debug the API I'm using [Altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design/). Can I define a fixed port number for altair that I can consider altair as trusted origin in the Django `settings.py` file (`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a maintainer of the [Altair GraphQL Client](https://altair.sirmuel.design/). Depending on how you choose to use Altair (with the browser extensions, or with the desktop apps), it might be possible to get past the CORS protection. By default, the browser extensions don't follow the CORS protection and can make requests with the same origin policy. If you're using the desktop apps, you can set the Origin header to get the requests to appear as coming from the same origin.

As for the CSRF token-based protection, one of the techniques you can use to solve it would be using [**pre request scripts**](https://altair.sirmuel.design/docs/features/prerequest-scripts.html) as described in this article: https://sirmuel.design/pre-requests-now-available-in-altair-graphql-client-c3b28892059c.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the hint. It's not urgent for me but I'll try it out at some point in time. In case someone else comments that it works I'll accept the anser.